# how to set default value of properties when object is constructing

Tags: php, oop

I have a simple class like below with some defined properties:

```
class model
{
    public $fakeUser = 'user';
    public $ENABLED_IF_LOGIN='disabled',
           $DISABLED_IF_LOGIN='',
           $HIDE_IF_LOGIN='',
           $SHOW_IF_LOGIN='hide',
           $SHOW_IF_EMAIL_VERIFIED='',
           $SHOW_IF_MOB_VERIFIED='',
           $SHOW_IF_INFO_VERIFIED='',
           $SHOW_IF_ADDR_VERIFIED='',

           $HIDE_IF_EMAIL_VERIFIED='',
           $HIDE_IF_MOB_VERIFIED='',
           $HIDE_IF_INFO_VERIFIED='',
           $HIDE_IF_ADDR_VERIFIED='';.

   function __construct()
   {

   }
}
```

these properties are changing during the execution.

how can I set default class properties when I call __construct().

**I tried this but I have problem with `new model`:**

```
$prop = get_object_vars(new model);
foreach($prop as $k=>$v)
     $this->{$k} = $v;
```

Comment: just use `$this->fakeUser = 'some val';` inside constructor. In addition u can have parameters while class instantiation and can use there values inside the __consturct() to set the values.

Comment: I can change properties like you said but I want to set defaults when i call __construct()

Comment: You have two options: 1. give the properties explicit values when you declare them - these will be its default values on `__construct`, or 2. declare the values in the `__construct method's body; e.g: `$this->someProperty = 'default_value'`. There is no functional difference between each approach. I'd tend to go for 1 myself. Also you are naming variables in `ALL_CAPS_AND_UNDERSCORES` which is generally recommended in PHP syntax conventions as a naming scheme for constants.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class model
{
    public $fakeUser = 'user';
    public $ENABLED_IF_LOGIN='disabled',
           $DISABLED_IF_LOGIN='',
           $HIDE_IF_LOGIN='',
           $SHOW_IF_LOGIN='hide',
           $SHOW_IF_EMAIL_VERIFIED='',
           $SHOW_IF_MOB_VERIFIED='',
           $SHOW_IF_INFO_VERIFIED='',
           $SHOW_IF_ADDR_VERIFIED='',

           $HIDE_IF_EMAIL_VERIFIED='',
           $HIDE_IF_MOB_VERIFIED='',
           $HIDE_IF_INFO_VERIFIED='',
           $HIDE_IF_ADDR_VERIFIED='';
}


$dirtyModel = new Model();
$dirtyModel->fakeUser = 'updatedFakeUser';

var_dump($dirtyModel);

// reset properties
$defaultModel  = new Model();
$defaultValues = get_object_vars($defaultModel);

foreach ($defaultValues as $k => $v) {
    $dirtyModel->{$k} = $v;
}

// the object after re-initialised
var_dump($dirtyModel);
```

Comment: ok. now how can I put default value back?

Comment: how can I set $fakeuser = 'user'

Comment: @Pooya to put the default value back you'd have to explicitly reassign a value to that property. You've defined that property as `public` so you just write `$this->fakeUser = 'user'` inside your class, or outside with: `$m = new Model(); $m->fakeUser = 'new name'; $m->fakeUser = 'name'` etc.

Comment: the problem is when I change the value I dont have the defalut value

Comment: @Pooya I just edited my answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: yes,kind of. but this is just example of my code and there is alot of properties. is there any other way. like using get_object_var() to do this automation.

Comment: @Pooya Given your question, that's not a problem per se. However I think what you mean to ask is "how can I re-initialise" the properties of an object? In this case I imagine Andy's edited answer above meets your requirements perfectly: an `init()` method that assigns default values to your class properties that can be called anytime (including `__construct()` time).

Comment: @Pooya If you really wanna automate it, you can use a hydrator. Extract the data from new object, and hydrate it to the object you want to re-initialise. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html

Comment: no need to zend. see my edit..

Comment: @Pooya I edited my answer. check it out.

Comment: thanks, you are close. but the problem is when I call new model in construct, the code get in a loop

Comment: @Pooya I'll refine my answer so it get closer to what you are trying to accomplish.